# vim key maps not working after reattach to tmux session over ssh

Tags: linux, vim, ssh, tmux

A little bit of context: I'm using vimx (that is X display campatible version of terminal vim for RedHat which gives me the ability to work with + and * X clipboard registers in vim). I do ssh to my server (with X forwarding using -Y option) and run vim (ie. vimx) in tmux. If I detach tmux session and attach to it again in the same ssh session, every thing works fine. However, if I logout of ssh session and log in back and then attach to my tmux session (which is running vim), then vim key binding and key mappings (like ctrl+n for new tab) and vim commands (like ":buffers" for displaying vim buffers or ":reg" for displaying registers) won't work any more until I close vim and reopen it again. I suspect that is a X11 display problem in vim and tmux, however I am not able to find what's going wrong in vim or tmux.

The summary of the problem and how to reproduce it:

1) do ssh to the server: ssh -Y user@server

2) open a new tmux session: tmux -2

3) open vimx: vimx myfile.cc

4) detach from tmux: ctrl+b d

5) logout ssh session: type exit in terminal or press ctrl+d

6) reconnect to the server: ssh -Y user@server

7) reattach to the tmux session: tmux -2 attach

in step 7, I will get reattached to the vimx session however, none of my vim key mappings or  commands for vim work now. (They do get fixed if I close and reopen vim but in that case what good tmux is for working with vim remotely?! :) )

Answer (score 0):

Rather than restarting vim, just use the :source command to reload your vimrc.

:so ~/.vimrc

That's easier than a restart and will work even in the middle of editing a file.